# 3D rotation about z-axis

Tags: 3d, coordinate-systems, rotations, transformation, projective-geometry

I am struggling to understand the 3D rotation.
[image]
I have one picture from internet which is drawn by me.
The initial object position is $A(x_1, y_1, z_1).$ We need rotate it into $A'(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ about $z$-axis by angle $\angle A'PA=\theta.$
And we take $P$ be the any point in $z$-axis. It makes $\angle APS=\phi.$

Now we find $cos \phi= \frac{PS}{AP}=\frac{x_1}{r}\Rightarrow x_1=rcos \phi.$ But we know $OQ =x_1$ but here slides take $PS =x_1$ and they forcefully match the answer which is wrong.

My question is  $PS =x_1$ or $OQ =x_1?$

Comment: How do you define $Q$? Note that $AS$ does not intersect the x-axis (it's not in the same plane)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Rot_Parall_1]

Given the point $A$ you shall imagine to draw a parallelepiped with a vertex on it,
the opposite vertex in $O$ and with the faces
parallel to the coordinate planes, as sketched.

Then a rotation around the axis $z$ will move any point in the space
keeping fixed the plane orthogonal to z in which they lay , i.e. the $z$ coordinate, along
a circle lying in that plane and centered on the $z$ axis, for an angle measured in that plane.

So $A=(x_1, y_1,z_1)$ will move to $A'=(x_2, y_2,z_1)$ (note z_1 is unchanged) , along
a circle centered at $P$, with radius $r=\sqrt{{x_1}^2+{y_1}^2}$, and angle $\theta$
measured in that plane $z=z_1$.
$S$ will move in that same plane, with the same angle, but on a circle of radius $x_1$.
$Q$ will do the same, on a circle with the same radius, but on the plane $z=0$ along
a circle centered at $O$, with an angle $\theta$ in that plane.

That is to say that the whole parallelepiped $OPSQA$ will rotate keeping fixed the edge
$OP$ and thus rotate to $OPS'Q'A'$, with
$$S'=(x_1 \cos \theta, x_1 \sin \theta, z_1), \; Q'=(x_1 \cos \theta, x_1 \sin \theta, 0)$$
while the expression for $A'$ is a little more complicated.

Comment: @G cab one thing tell how to go A to P?

Comment: @Niyon: do not get exactly your question: you can go from A to P directly along the segment AP joining them, or you can go from A to S and from S to P, or ..

Comment: @G you mean plane z1 is orthogonal to z?

Comment: @Niyon it is the plane $z=z_1$ , i.e. the plane $PAS$, which is orthogonal to the z axis. Added a further clarification in the answer, hope it is clear

Comment: @Niyon: do you know cylindrical coordinates ?

Comment: @G One thing tell , I have given $A(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ so why everyone choose $P(0,0,z_1)$  to rotate about z-axis?

Comment: @G. Cab please help my this question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4291739/3d-shearing-w-r-t-x-axis

Comment: @Niyon: it is worthy to consider the point P because that is the center of the circle along which A is moving

Comment: @G cab.. You have great concepts. And please help above question

Answer (score 2):

Note that a rotation around the $z$ axis does not change the $z$ coordinate of a point. That means you can perform $A\to A'$ only if $z_2=z_1$. Then the plane $A'PA$ is at a constant $z$ value, so it is parallel to the $x-y$ plane ($z=0$). If you want to see a point on the $x$ axis that is at a distance $x_1$ from $O$, you need to look in the horizontal plane ($x-z$), and draw a parallel to teh $z$ axis from $S$. Then $OPSQ$ looks like a parallelogram.

Comment: You mean A is calculated from P not from origin O in my diagram?

Comment: $A$ is from the origin. But the rotation happens only in the plane parallel to the $xy$ plane. You can project $A$ and $A'$ onto the $xy$ plane, by drawing segments parallel to $OP$.

Comment: My question is PS=x1 in my diagram?I mean A is calculated from P not from origin O in my diagram? –

Comment: You mean the offset parallel to the $x$ axis? Then yes. The coordinates are $A=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$, $A'=(x_2,y_2,z_1)$, $P=(0,0,z_1)$, and $S=(x_1,0,z_1)$

Comment: You mean offset is PS?

Comment: Yes, $|PS|=|x_1|$. If $z_1=0$ then $P=O=(0,0,0)$ and $S=(x_1,0,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

PS= $x_1$ is what you mean.

There does not exist any such point as Q you marked as final coordinate, it is parallel to line $SP$.

[image]

A is calculated from A, Q, and P along with a point opposite to origin O , in xz plane, I did not label it .

Comment: one thing tell how $A(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ is calculated?I mean first PS=x1, then SA=y1?

Comment: I shall draw and show you. Give me 15 mins.

Comment: And A is calculated from O or P?

Comment: Is it clearer now? All coordinates should be parallel to x,y, z axes.

Comment: Better to draw Z2=0 for 3d effect and z offset.

Comment: "A is calculated from A, Q, and P  "--- don't understand

Comment: what you mean "A is calculated from A"?

Comment: Please excuse me. feeling sleepy. Please try this one. $ (A,A')=(4,3,0),(2,5,-3)$

Comment: please help my this question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4291739/3d-shearing-w-r-t-x-axis

Comment: You've taken the incorrect diagram from the question and reinforced the incorrect parts. We would be better off without this diagram.

Comment: It was intended only to temporarily guide the OP faced at that time at just the part he was facing, viz., correct parallels to axes. I opted not to supply the full answer/diagram that was of course possible from me ....  is in keeping with the present policy of  adequate useful guidance indicated by our community moderators AmWhy etal. Hope it is in order.